# ASPX C# Form that automatically adds another row of fields If Fields have Values

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, input, field

So basically what i want to do is, automatically create a 2nd row of fields if the first initial row is filled out.
It does not need to be triggered by a button, necessarily. How would i do this?

Comment: you must use javascript to do this

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some JavaScript tot resolve this cliënt side. For instance a postback on the last cell modification.

Answer (score 0):

Represent this as a Grid control that can be represented by a DataTable. Each row will be a DataRow. Bind the DataTable to this grid.

Do a postback for each of the individual fields in the row. Run a method to check if all fields are non-empty for each postback. If yes, add a new row. Rebind DataTable to the form.

Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Knockout.js video on MSDN.

The sample code is there too to add fields on the fly.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08